# jQuery: Select parent sibling element in stacked UL

Tags: jquery, list, select, element

This is REALLY driving me nuts!! I'm no real developer, but there MUST be an easy way to achive what I want. I'm working on this for hours, but maybe some skilled person can help me with this.

**The situation:**

I have a nested UL list with headlines in the submenus (h3 class="subMenuHeader").

Every h3 with the class "subMenuHeader" should be filled with the link name of the previous anchor-text (e.g. "Foo").

**How it should work**

```
<ul> <!-- First Level -->
  <li>
    <a> Foo </a>

    <ul> <!-- Second Level -->
      <h3 class="subMenuHeader"> Foo </h3>
      <li>
        <a> Bar </a>

        <ul> <!-- Third Level -->
          <h3 class="subMenuHeader"> Bar </h3>
          <li>
            <a>Whoop</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried ALL combinations to select the (a)-Tag in front of the ".subMenuHeader"-class, but there seems to be a serious problem in my logic.

As a real jQuery-Noob I've tried something like this:

```
var x = jQuery(".subMenuHeader").closest('ul').parent('li').find('a').text();

jQuery('.subMenuHeader').text(x);
```

But as you can see, this ulitmately doesn't work. It actually shows ALL texts of any (a)'s that follow that selection and it doesn't reduce/specity the content, the deeper it goes in the DOM. I always end up with a gigantic string of (a)-texts...

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this.........

```
jQuery('.subMenuHeader').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).parent().siblings('a').html());
});
```

(if wants to change content after page load then as below)

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.subMenuHeader').each(function() {
            $(this).html($(this).parent().siblings('a').html());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` to get first `li` parent and then target first `a` inside with `find()` and `:first`

```js
$('.subMenuHeader').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).closest('li').find('a:first').text())
})
```

```css
h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> <!-- First Level -->
  <li>
    <a> Foo </a>
    <ul> <!-- Second Level -->
      <h3 class="subMenuHeader"></h3>
      <li>
        <a> Bar </a>
        <ul> <!-- Third Level -->
          <h3 class="subMenuHeader"></h3>
          <li>
            <a>Whoop</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to adjust it:

Using `first`

```js
    var x = jQuery(".subMenuHeader").closest('ul').parent('li').find('a:first').text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> <!-- First Level -->
  <li>
    <a> Foo </a>

    <ul> <!-- Second Level -->
      <h3 class="subMenuHeader"> Foo </h3>
      <li>
        <a> Bar </a>

        <ul> <!-- Third Level -->
          <h3 class="subMenuHeader"> Bar </h3>
          <li>
            <a>Whoop</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Using `prev()` or `siblings()` to get prior sibling of the ul

```js
var x = jQuery(".subMenuHeader").closest('ul').prev('a').text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> <!-- First Level -->
  <li>
    <a> Foo </a>

    <ul> <!-- Second Level -->
      <h3 class="subMenuHeader"> Foo </h3>
      <li>
        <a> Bar </a>

        <ul> <!-- Third Level -->
          <h3 class="subMenuHeader"> Bar </h3>
          <li>
            <a>Whoop</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```